# IS there an FTP tool that can search for a phrase in all the files in a directory?

Tags: search, ftp, file-search

Probably not, just need to clear up a question between me and a colleague.

Wondering if there's an FTP tool that will search for a phrase within all the files in a directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have more than just FTP access then it is possible with WinSCP and grep:

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/remote_command

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/custom_commands#search_text

Answer (score 2):

Not via FTP, no.  FTP does not have a search or grep function for files, it's simply for transferring.

Answer (score 1):

You can script this in PowerShell using [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library):

- recursively list all files in a directory using the [`Session.ListDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory);
- download files one by one to a local temporary folder using the [`Session.GetFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles);
- search the contents of local copies (using the cmdlet [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)) and remove the copy afterwards.

For complete code, see [Search recursively for text in remote directory / Grep files over SFTP/FTP protocol](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_recursive_search_text).

---

If you have a shell access, you can search remotely (as the answer by @Shevek already pointed out).
See [Searching for a text/string within a directory](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/custom_commands#search_text).

But that's not FTP-based solution anymore.